# JavaScript Return function not true result

Tags: javascript, function

I have an array and a function checkMember. I want to check, do the member have in the array? But checkMember function only true if I call checkMember('Cody'). I don't understand. Please help me!

```js
var fe01 = [
  {name: 'Giang', fee: 5, fea: 6},
  {name: 'Zack', fee: 7, fea: 7},
  {name: 'Henry', fee: 8, fea: 8},
  {name: 'Cody', fee: 9, fea: 9}
];    

function checkMember(name){
  var result;
  for(var i = 0; i < fe01.length; i++){
     console.log(`${fe01[i].name}`)
     if(fe01[i].name == name){
       //console.log(true);
       result = true;
     } else{
       //console.log(false)
       result = false;
     }
  }     
  return result;
}

console.log(checkMember('Cody'));//true
console.log(checkMember('Giang'));//false
```

Comment: not too surprising? Instead of stopping once you find it, you keep checking the next element, which invalidates your find. Having said that, why on earth write all this code when [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this.

**Using `for..loop` with [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement:**

```js
var fe01 = [
            {name: 'Giang', fee: 5, fea: 6},
            {name: 'Zack', fee: 7, fea: 7},
            {name: 'Henry', fee: 8, fea: 8},
            {name: 'Cody', fee: 9, fea: 9}
        ];

function checkMember(name){
    var result;
    for(var i = 0; i < fe01.length; i++){
        //console.log(`${fe01[i].name}`)
        if(fe01[i].name == name){
            //console.log(true);
            result = true;
            break;     // jump out of the loop here
        } else{
            //console.log(false)
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(checkMember('Cody'));//true
console.log(checkMember('Giang'));//true
```

**Using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:**

```js
var fe01 = [ {name: 'Giang', fee: 5, fea: 6}, {name: 'Zack', fee: 7, fea: 7},
    {name: 'Henry', fee: 8, fea: 8}, {name: 'Cody', fee: 9, fea: 9}];

function checkMember(search){
    return fe01.some(({name}) => name == search);
}
console.log(checkMember('Cody'));//true
console.log(checkMember('Giang'));//true
console.log(checkMember('abc'));//false
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain to me "using for..loop with break statement"? Or share with me the keyword?

Comment: Actually, I have already shared a link for [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement. Basically, right now you loop keeps on running even if a match is found. So, when a match is found then `result = true` but in next loop again no match is found and thus `result = false` and thus we see false for match found also. We just need to break the loop as soom as first mtach is found.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
    var fe01 = [
            {name: 'Giang', fee: 5, fea: 6},
            {name: 'Zack', fee: 7, fea: 7},
            {name: 'Henry', fee: 8, fea: 8},
            {name: 'Cody', fee: 9, fea: 9}
        ];

function checkMember(name){
            return fe01.some(obj => obj.name == name)
        }

console.log(checkMember('Cody'));//true
console.log(checkMember('personX'));//false
```